# Compiler debug log: Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI Found the following

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, binance

0

I deployed a contract of a token that has up to nine other files imported to the binance blockchain. I have done everything I can read and try in order to verify it. But it keeps giving me error.
Compiler debug log: Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI Found the following ContractName(s) in source code : Address, Context, IERC20, IUniswapV2Factory, IUniswapV2Pair, IUniswapV2Router01, IUniswapV2Router02, Ownable, RentCoin, SafeMath But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2) For troubleshooting, you can try compiling your source code with the Remix - Solidity IDE and check for exceptions

My contract was compiled and deployed using Remix and optimization was set to 200. My compiler version is 0.6.12 and the link to the flattened contract is below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/100J73q4hutqqmT1tZEuMn46YYFmzYaT0/view?usp=sharing

I understand that this contract involves constructors but I really need a practical guide on how to locate them and convert them to the right-abi-encoded JSON format that the verification page may accept.

Comment: Remix has a plugin "Etherscan - Contract Verification" did you try it?

Comment: Yes @Ismael, but apparently it does not support contracts deployed on binance blockchain. Still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

hello hope you are doing well,
searched alot about this issue but the solution about this is contact with BSCscan and ask for help.
hopefully this is helpful for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).